# Listing registered users from IdentityServer in another application

Tags: identityserver4

I have a requirement to create an admin UI where I need to list all users registered on IdentityServer to start assigning permissions and roles. This application internally uses PolicyServer, but as a superadmin user, I would need to see all users registered on IdentityServer. Here IdentityServer is responsible for authentication and the other application that uses PolicyServer is responsible for the authorization.

Which is the correct way to proceed:
1- This admin UI application should be connected to the same database that IdentityServer uses to get all the users?
2 Or should I need to extend IdentityServer on this way?:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html

I followed this issue here:
IdentityServer/IdentityServer3#2607
but still, it is not clear for me how to proceed on the question above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the users database is usually provided by ASP.NET Identity, not so Identity Server.

I had the same issue and I went on to develop the admin Web app in the same host as Identity Server, thus using the database connection to get to the users (and the API resources, clients, etc.).

I argue that this is the simplest way to achieve what you want. And still allows you to provide a complete API on your Identity Server for external apps. I also did that (for scenarios where client apps are allowed to view/edit the user profile, for example). The API was built using plain ASP.NET Core MVC.